# How to set a max number of goroutines to complete the work?

Tags: go, goroutine

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(len(work))

sem := make(chan struct{}, 10)

wgDone := make(chan bool)

for i < len(work)-1 {
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        sem <- struct{}{}
        defer func() {
            <-sem
        }()
        worker(work[i])
    }()
    i = i + 1
}

go func() {     
    wg.Wait()
    close(wgDone)
}()
```

I only want **10 new goroutines** at a time performing the work. This is my current solution, it blocks goroutines from continuing so there is only 10 at a time. How can I change this so it doesn't create an abundance of goroutines that are blocked waiting to work and instead only creates 10 that complete all the work?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 12):

Based on the use case one of these methods is useful:

1. Using `max` number of new goroutines and a channel as a queue ([The Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mX66PQkY1B1)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    const max = 10
    queue := make(chan int, max)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(wg, queue)
    }
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        queue <- i
    }
    close(queue)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, queue chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for job := range queue {
        fmt.Print(job, " ") // a job
    }
}
```

---

2. Using a buffered channel as a semaphore to **limits** the **new goroutines number** to the **max** number ([The Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/f946DT7C46h)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    const max = 10
    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, max)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        semaphore <- struct{}{} // acquire
        wg.Add(1)
        go limited(i, wg, semaphore)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
func limited(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, semaphore chan struct{}) {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Println("i =", i) // a job
    <-semaphore // release
}
```

---

3. Using a buffered channel as a semaphore to **limits** the number of **jobs** to the max number - here number of goroutines are more than max number ([The Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PTI7dsAHVbt)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    const max = 10
    semaphore := make(chan struct{}, max)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go limited(i, wg, semaphore)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
func limited(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, semaphore chan struct{}) {
    defer wg.Done()
    semaphore <- struct{}{} // acquire
    fmt.Println("i =", i) // a job
    <-semaphore // release
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So if you want only say 10 workers you should spawn 10 workers listening to a job Queue this can be a channel you can push the inputs to this channel and workers will pick it

Now it will only block jobs when the queue is full so you can decide the queue size based on your use case

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var jobQ chan int
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    jobQ = make(chan int, 100)
    
    go func(){
        wg.Add(1)
        defer wg.Done() 
        //Spawn 10 workers
        for i:=0;i<10;i++ {
            fmt.Println("Spawn :", i)
            wg.Add(1)
            go worker(jobQ)
        }
    }()
    
    for i := 0; i< 1000;i++ {
        jobQ<- i
    }
    close(jobQ)
    
    
    wg.Wait()
}



func worker(jobs chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for job:=range jobs {
        fmt.Println(job)
    }
}
```

Now you can customize this and find other worker pool implementations; worker pools are used a lot and you will find different implementaions

Playground : https://play.golang.org/p/lzIMRUCvqR9